# Location of executables in MPICH?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

Do I need to
place my executables individually in each
machine in MPICH or is the executable in the master
node shared across all systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends.

If your machines do have a shared file-system (NFS, GPFS, Lustre, ...) then MPICH can spawn executables from there avoiding you to copy the executable (and their library dependencies) to each node.

However, if your nodes do not have a shared file-system, then each node requires its own binary (and again, its library dependencies) so as the mpi launcher can run them.